# "before yet" "in short ventures"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> The American has dwindled into an Odd Fellow (17) — one who may be
>   known by the development of his organ of gregariousness, and a
>   manifest lack of intellect and cheerful self-reliance; whose first and
>   chief concern, on coming into the world, is to see that the almshouses
>   are in good repair; and, **before yet** he has lawfully donned the virile
>   garb, to collect a fund for the support of the widows and orphans that
>   may be; who, **in short ventures** to live only by the aid of the Mutual
>   Insurance company, which has promised to bury him decently.  -Thoreau

1. What does "before yet" and its sentence mean?
2. How to paraphrase "in short ventures"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first point is mostly an unexpected word order:

> **before yet** he has lawfully donned the virile garb, ...

We would normally write) as far as word order is concerned as:

> **before** he has lawfully donned the virile garb **yet**, ...

But this use of *yet* still feels archaic. I guess a more natural way today would be to write:

> **even before** he has lawfully donned the virile garb, ...

or, as Tᴚoɯɐuo correctly points out:

> **before** he has **even** lawfully donned the virile garb, ...

Or simply leave it at *before* on its own.

---

In your second part, I feel a comma might be missing. If I change

> who, in short ventures to live...

into

> who, in short **,** ventures to live...

I feel the sentence becomes much clearer. After a long, long sentence, the author recaptures, in short, the main idea. It is simply an interjection that could be left out without changing the meaning much.

Comment: How to paraphrase "lawfully don the virile garb"?

Comment: @LeonZero Be a man in the eyes of the law. Garb = clothes, virile = masculine, of a grown man.

Comment: +1. The comma is helpful but unnecessary.  We know *from the syntax* that **short** is not an adjective modifying a noun **ventures** but that the phrase is **in short** (that is, **in brief**) and that **ventures** is a verb. The *who*-clause needs a verb, and it is **ventures**, complemented by "to live..."

Comment: +1 also for **even before**. A contemporary colloquial paraphrase of "*before yet* he has {done something}** would be "before he has *even* {done something}. Compare this passage from Emerson: *Linnaeus projects his system, and lays out his twenty-four classes of plants, before yet he has found in nature a single plant to justify certain of his classes.* https://books.google.com/books?id=y4_SXyx8zwkC&pg=PA166&dq=%22before+yet+he+has%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2u8nIl6TUAhUC6yYKHWodA7kQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22before%20yet%20he%20has%22&f=false